# Using .hasClass() to verify all my inputs are front-end valid to submit form not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to verify that all the inputs in this form are of class .has-success before I allow the user to press the submit button. The problem is that once all the inputs are reached and they all have the .has-success class, the button won't activate. Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
$('#groupUsuario, #passwordVerificationUsuario, #passwordUsuario, #nombreUsuario').on('click change blur focus', function(){
     if ($('#groupUsuario').hasClass('has-success') && $('#passwordVerificationUsuario').hasClass('has-success') && $('#passwordUsuario').hasClass('has-success') && $('#nombreUsuario').hasClass('has-success')){
        $('#ingresarUsuario').attr('disabled', false);
     } else  $('#ingresarUsuario').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="well text-center">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <h1 class="text-center">Weiver - Usuarios</h1>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div id="nameUserValidation" class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="nombreUsuario">Nombre del Usuario</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" id="nombreUsuario" placeholder="nombre del cine">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="passwordUserValidation" class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="passwordUsuario">Contraseña</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordUsuario" id="passwordUsuario" placeholder="nombre del cine">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="passwordVerificationUserValidation" class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="passwordVerificationUsuario">Verificar Contraseña</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordVerificationUsuario" id="passwordVerificationUsuario" placeholder="nombre del cine">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="groupUserValidation" class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="groupUsuario">Grupo al que Pertenece</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="groupUsuario" id="groupUsuario">
                                            <option value="nada">Seleccione un Grupo</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="well" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
                                    <p style="text-align: justify"><strong>Nota: </strong>Que todos los campos estan verdes no significa que la informacion ingresada esta correcta. Solo significa que se ingreso informacion en todos los campos, que se terminara de validar cuando se mande al servidor.</p>
                                    <button type="submit" name="ingresarUsuario" id="ingresarUsuario" class="btn btn-success pull-right" disabled="disabled">ingresar Usuario</button>
                                    <a href="menu.php" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Menú Principal</a>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It must be something silly or so, maybe someone can spot the error, I've been coding for like 10 hours straight now, I'm kinda dizzy. I have the same example on another form, and on that one, it does work, the button will change its disabled attribute to "" when all the inputs being checked have the .has-success class.

Any help as well as constructive criticism will be welcomed!

Comment: Instead of using `.attr()`, you should use the `.prop()` method to disable (or re-enable) form inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I encountered this sort of issue before. Have you tried removing the `disabled` attribute instead ?
Like that :

```
$('#groupUsuario, #passwordVerificationUsuario, #passwordUsuario, #nombreUsuario').on('click change blur focus', function(){
    if ($('#groupUsuario').hasClass('has-success') && $('#passwordVerificationUsuario').hasClass('has-success') && $('#passwordUsuario').hasClass('has-success') && $('#nombreUsuario').hasClass('has-success')){
        $('#ingresarUsuario').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#ingresarUsuario').attr('disabled', true);
    }
```

});

On a side note, I would also suggest adding a default class (or data-* attribute if it isn't related to style at all) to your inputs and compare on each `click`, `change`, `blur`, `focus` the length of the two jQuery arrays : `$('.need-success')` and `$('.has-success')`. That would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would try isolating your issue by using FireBug or something similar to observe if your calls to .attr('disabled', ...) are hit correctly.

Consider using .removeAttr('disabled') rather than .attr('disabled', false).

Comment: OR even `.prop('disabled', false)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pay no mind. I have found the error. I should be using the div's ID to set the error class from bootstrap, not the actual input ID.

Been for 40min trying to find the error. It now works.

here is the code:

```
 $('#nombreUsuario, #passwordUsuario, #passwordVerificationUsuario, #groupUsuario').on(
'click blur focus mouseleave mouseenter change', function(){
     if (
           $('#nameUserValidation').hasClass('has-success')
           &&
           $('#passwordUserValidation').hasClass('has-success')
           &&
           $('#passwordVerificationUserValidation').hasClass('has-success')
           &&
           $('#groupUserValidation').hasClass('has-success')
         ){
              $('#ingresarUsuario').attr('disabled', false);
     } else   $('#ingresarUsuario').attr('disabled', true); 
});
```

I was using the same ID's from the inputs on the .hasClass() validation.